# How to change the mode dynamically in codemirror on encounter of a particular expression?

Tags: html, text-editor, freemarker, codemirror

In the textarea whenever '<' is encountered the mode should be html and for '<#' or '<@' or '$', the mode should be ftl. In the code that I have written

```
function determineCodeMirrorType(cm) {
  if (cm.getOption('mode') == 'text/ftl') {
    checkAndSwitchToHTML(cm, cm.getValue());
  } else if (cm.getOption('mode') == 'text/html') {
    checkAndSwitchToFTL(cm, cm.getValue());
  }
}

function checkAndSwitchToHTML(cm, val) {
  if (/^\s*</.test(val)) {
    cm.setOption("mode", "text/html");
  }
}

function checkAndSwitchToFTL(cm, val) {
  if (/[<#|<@|$]/.test(val)) {
    cm.setOption("mode", "text/ftl");
  }
}

function buildCMInstance(mode, value) {
  var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    mode:mode,
    value:value,
    lineNumbers:true,
    onChange:function(cmInstance){ 
      determineCodeMirrorType(cmInstance); //The call to this function is not made.
    })
  });
  return cm;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var cm = buildCMInstance("text/ftl")
});
```

I want to know is there any option that can be initiated which allows the code to change dynamically by making a call to the function "determineCodeMirrorType".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange` does not exist in recent CodeMirror versions. You have to register the event handler by calling `cm.on("change", function(cm, change) { .... })`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marijn. I used the above method but the state of the text editor is changing continuously when using the change event. Can you suggest another event which allows both the modes to run simultaneously and also the autocomplete function works whenever the appropriate token for the particular mode is parsed.